# Having an issue with navigation buttons while using Lightbox 2

Tags: lightbox2

I have a slideshow of 12 images in place. When I click on the first image, the right arrow pops up which allows me to scroll to the next image. When I do so, the second image has no next button. The same is true for every picture except the first. The really odd thing is that when I hit the X button to close out, it scrolls to the next image. The previous button works correctly on all of the pictures, but there's something wrong with both the next button and the close(X) button

Answer (score 0):

"Next" button is overlapping with "X" button.
If you hover a little lower from "X" button the "Next" button will appear.
I solved this by adding a `position:absolute` to `.lb-prev, .lb-next` to `lightbox.css`